# How to union a two select lenght result in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to take the minimum and maximum length of the start_station_name and combine them into one table, but when I used union, an error occurred.

Should I use Union to do this? I don't know another method to 'combine' these results.

Here is my syntax:

```
select start_station_name, min(length(start_station_name)) from bike_rides
order by start_station_name asc, length(start_station_name)
limit 1

union all

select start_station_name, max(length(start_station_name)) from bike_rides
order by start_station_name asc, length(start_station_name)
limit 1
```

Thank You

Comment: You need to put the subqueries in parentheses to use `LIMIT 1` for each.

Comment: You don't need `LIMIT 1`. Since each query uses aggregation without `GROUP BY`, they just return 1 row.

Comment: Why do you need `ORDER BY`, since there's just one row containing the minimum or maximum length?

Comment: because actually i just wanted to simulate a case on Hackerrank on my data, i wanted to take the first start_station_name with alphabetical order (assuming there is 2 station name that has the same length), i wanted to take the first one that appears based on the alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `MIN()` and `MAX()`. Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

To use LIMIT with `UNION`, you need to put each subquery in parentheses.

```
(SELECT start_station_name, LENGTH(start_station_name) AS len
 FROM bike_rides
 ORDER BY len, start_station_name
 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT start_station_name, LENGTH(start_station_name) AS len
 FROM bike_rides
 ORDER BY len DESC, start_station_name
 LIMIT 1)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a7912/1)

Answer (score 0):

while using aggregate functions you have to use group by.

```sql
SELECT start_station_name, MIN(length(start_station_name)) AS len FROM bike_rides GROUP BY start_station_name
UNION ALL
SELECT start_station_name, MAX(length(start_station_name)) AS len FROM bike_rides GROUP BY start_station_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a simpler solution to this problem -- assuming the names are ASCII letters -- is to make the names all the same length and using `max()` and `min()` on them.  Conveniently, spaces are ordered before any letters or numbers, so you can use:

```
select trim(max(lpad(50, start_station_name, ' '))) as longest_name,
       trim(min(lpad(50, start_station_name, ' '))) as shortest_name       
from bike_rides;
```

The 50 is arbitrary and should be at least as large as the longest name.